# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET sc-status 200 sc-win32status 64

Tags: iis, networking, iis-10, f5

I have an F5 load balancing setup configured with two servers. My MVC web application, which incorporates jQuery, and Bootstrap, is hosted on an IIS server with an SSL certificate. However, when accessing the application via HTTPS from outside the server, it often or sometimes results in a 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' error, with intermittent failures to load JavaScript and CSS files to the client. Strangely, upon reloading the page, the assets load properly, and the page functions as expected. This issue did not occur when the application was accessed via HTTP, where it worked properly without any issues. What could be the reason behind this problem?

Log from IIS

#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0

#Version: 1.0

#Date: 2024-03-18 00:00:00

#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2024-03-18 00:00:00 10.32.000.00 GET / - 81 - 10.32.2040.3 - - 200 0 64 2

2024-03-18 00:00:02 10.32.000.00 GET / - 81 - 10.32.200.2 - - 200 0 64 2

2024-03-18 00:00:05 10.32.000.00 GET / - 81 - 10.32.200.3 - - 200 0 64 3

Comment: You will have to capture network packets on multiple locations to determine who sent the TCP RST packet. Please involve your network administrators first. Not yet a programming related question.

Comment: There are many reasons for `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error, you need more information to troubleshoot this issue, maybe you can check the Event Viewer for related error messages.

Comment: [Same question you have posted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1623491/sc-status-200-sc-win32status-64).